# setting up a python http function in firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an app that is meant to integrate with third-party apps. These apps should be able to trigger a function when data changes.

The way I was envisioning this, I would use a node function to safely prepare data for the third parties, and get the url to call from the app's configuration on firestore. I would call that url from the node function, and wait for it to return, updating results as necessary (actually, triggering a push notification). -- these third-party functions would tend to be python functions, so my demo should be in python.

I have the initial node function and firestore setup so that I am currently triggering a ECONNREFUSED -- because I don't know how to set up the third-party function.

Let's say this is the function I need to trigger:

```
def hello_world(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request_json and 'name' in request_json:
        name = request_json['name']
    else:
        name = 'World'
    return 'Hello, {}!\n'.format(name)
```

Do I need to set up a separate gcloud account to host this function, or can I include it in my firestore functions? If so, how do I deploy this to firestore? Typically with my node functions, I am running `firebase deploy` and it automagically finds my functions from my index.js file.

Comment: I'm confused about what technology you use. You say Firestore (a database), but I see no Firestore code and the description seems more like you're trying to use Cloud Functions (executing snippets of your code on Google's servers). Are you talking about Cloud Functions (either from [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) or [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) directly)?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, that's right, this just needs to be a function responding to an http call -- essentially a GCF. That http call would be fired off from a firebase function already built and operating correctly in firestore. My question is, do I have to create a new GCF project just for this function, or can I publish it in a similar way to my firestore functions? I note that it appears that I could publish http functions (essentially GCF) directly in firestore if they were node: I would jjust change how they were triggered. But this is a python script.

Comment: There is no such thing a "a Cloud Function operating in Firestore". If you mean "a Cloud Function that is triggered by Firestore", then the question makes more sense. I'll write an answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether Cloud Functions that are triggered by Cloud Firestore can co-exist in a project with Cloud Functions that are triggered by HTTP(S) requests, then the answer is "yes they can". There is no need to set up a separate (Firebase or Cloud) project for each function type.

However: when you deploy your Cloud Functions through the Firebase CLI with `firebase deploy`, it will remove any functions that it finds in the project, that are not in the code. If you have functions both in Python and in Node.js, there is never a single codebase that contains both, so a blanket deploy would always delete some of your functions. So in that case, you should use the [granular deploy option of the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#deploy_specific_functions).

Comment: Thank you, Frank. How do I deploy the demo script that I provided?

Comment: Ah, I just realize. Are your Firestore-triggered Functions written in Node.js? While you can have multiple environment on a single project, you will need to deploy them granularly. So typically that would mean using the GCP tools for deploying, combines with [granular deploy with the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#deploy_specific_functions).